# anomaly detection and outlier Difference

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

I was figuring out the real time data processing and come across the term 
***"anomaly detection "*** 
I know about Outlier and its treatment in case we've got in our study,
Is  ***"anomaly detection "*** is same as ***"Outliers "*** ??
If not then what are the key differences.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually "Anomaly detection" refers to an area of machine learning that aims at the identification of samples, items, patterns that are "outliers" to the expected distribution. In that field falls application as fraud detection, fault detection, intrusion detection and so on...

Comment: So in a way , we can say  "Anomaly detection" is "Outliers".

Comment: Eventually, I would say that they are related but they are not the same thing. "Outlier" is a statistical concept where an observation is "distant" from the expected distribution of the observation. "Anomaly detection" is an area of machine learning that aims at outlier detection.

Answer (score 0):

The `Anomalies` and `Outliers` can be used interchangeably. One more word is `Novelties`. However, `Novelties` can be considered as a new mode of a system and `Novelties` should be less serious than `Anomalies` and `Outliers`.